# Adding a single record in SAS?

Tags: sas

I've found how to append a table to a base with proc append. I'm wondering if there is a simpler way (that doesn't require creating a temporary holding table) that adds a single record? All solutions I find require several lines, I'm wondering if there's something more straightforward like the "delete" command that I'm missing?

Answer (score 2):

As I think you have found, there are multiple options.  If you have values you want to add, the one that makes the most sense from a lay person reading your code is a PROC SQL `INSERT` statement.

```
data test;
format a best. b $8. c date9.;
a = 1;
b = "ABC";
c = "01JAN2015"d;
run;

proc sql;
insert into test (b,c,a) 
values ("DEF", "01JAN2014"d, 2);
quit;
```

The specification of the variable order `(b,c,a)` is optional.  If it is not specified, then the values must be in the same order as the columns on the table.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a data step with a `modify` statement to insert additional rows. Any other sort of data step involves creating a temporary file and replacing the original, which is undesirable when you're making a small change to a large dataset.

```
data class;
    set sashelp.class;
run;

data class;
    modify class;
    Name = 'ZZZ';
    output;
    stop;
run;
```

This reads in the first row of the dataset to the PDV and then appends it with an updated value of `Name`, leaving the values of all the other variables as they were in the first row.

N.B. without the `stop` statement, this will cause an infinite loop, as SAS will alternately add and append records indefinitely, never getting any closer to the end of the dataset.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to conditionally add observations from another dataset then you can use `output` to tell SAS to output the PDV as it stands:

**Generate example input datasets:**

```
data source1 ; 
  do i=1 to 10 ;
    output ;
  end ;
run; 

data source2 ;
  i=999 ;
  do j=100 to 0 by -10 ;
    output ;
  end ;
run ;
```

**Code to add in single record:**

Read in `source1` and output the observation before testing the condition (`i=5`) to read in an observation from `source2`:

```
data want ;
  set source1 ;
  output ;
  if i=5 then do ;
    set source2 ;
    output ;
  end ;
run;
```

However, it's important to know the interaction between the two `set` statements:

- Any variables that are in BOTH datasets will be overwritten by either `set` statement - so the value of this variable will be updated even if the previous value has not been output (see observation number 6 of the `want` dataset)
- Any variables that are only in ONE dataset will effectively be 'retained' across observations until another `set` statement for the appropriate source dataset is encountered (see observations 7 to 11 of the `want` dataset)

For details of the PDV processing logic see [here](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrcon/62955/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000961108.htm)

Comment: Any data step approach will involve creating a temporary holding dataset before replacing the original, which is something that the asker is trying to avoid.

Comment: ...unless you use a modify statement, as per my answer.