# Add one additional row to SAS data set

Tags: sas, proc

I have the following data:

```
Person      Variable1        Variable2
001         X32              X45
002         X33              X99
```

I'd like to add one row to the data set:

```
Person      Variable1        Variable2
001         X32              X45
002         X33              X99
003         X67              X12
```

I'd like do so with either a DATA or PROC SQL statement
Thanks for any insight

Comment: Please show what code you have tried.  It will help others help you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding a single record in SAS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30733545/adding-a-single-record-in-sas)

Answer (score 1):

SQL INSERT statement works

```
  insert into mydata values ('003', 'X67', 'X12');
```

Answer (score 1):

output statement will helps:

```
data test;
  set test end = eof;
  output;
  if eof then do;
    Person = '003';
    Variable1 = 'X67';
    Variable2 = 'X12';
    output;
  end;
run;
```